# AWS S3: how to explain all these GET/PUT requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just signed up for AWS free tier and created an S3 bucket with only one file to test it (private access, no public permissions, no versioning). I notice that in the billing dashboard put/get counts steadily keep increasing and are into hundreds now, even though I made only one upload and a couple of views of that file. When I enabled access log of the S3 bucket, most of the requests seem system generated from the Amazon domain to query bucket encryption, ACL, versioning, etc. Even when I delete all the buckets, I still see put/get request counts to keep on increasing. I am wondering where are those coming from? If those are system generated then why do they count against free tier limits?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled Cloudtrail? Macie? Or perhaps been playing around with Glue crawlers or bucket events for SQS/SNS/Lambda use? There are several Amazon services which may hit your S3 buckets as part of their normal operation.

You might also find answers in https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-deleted-s3-charges/

Comment: Not to mention opening S3 in the console.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend reading this AWS documentation -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/viewing-bucket-key-settings.html

PUT -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html

GET - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html

POST - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

COPY - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html